# JavaScript - Creating a deepSet() with multiple-level Array support

Tags: javascript, lodash

So I need a `deepSet()` function in my React application and I know there are dozens of libraries available for that.  However, my requirements are beyond that of the standard `deepSet()`.  My function has to be able to support Arrays, and multiple Arrays in the path.

Example, simple `deepSet()`

```
var obj = { one: { two: {three: 'a'}} };
deepSet(obj, 'one.two.three', 'yay');
// {one: {two: { three: 'yay' } } }
```

What I need it to support (and have working)

```
var obj = { one: { two: [{three: 'a'}, {three: 'a'}] } };
deepSet(obj, 'one.two[].three', 'yay');
// { one: { two: [{three: 'yay'}, {three: 'yay'}] }};
```

What I also need it to support, and ***DO NOT*** have working yet

```
var obj = { one: { two: [{three: [{four:'a'}, {four:'b'}]}, {three: [{four:'a'}, {four:'b'}]}]}};
deepSet(obj, 'one.two[].three[].four', 'yay');
// { one: { two: [{three: [{four:'yay'}, {four:'yay'}]}, {three: [{four:'yay'}, {four:'yay'}]}]}};
```

My problem is that I can't figure out how to get that next level of arrays and iterate over them.  I think a recursive approach is best here, but I can't figure that out to handle 2 or more Arrays.  I've spent a few hours on this and am turning to SO for help.

Here's the algorithm I have so far, that supports 0 and 1 level of Arrays.

```
const deepSet = (object, path, value) => {
    let fields = path.split('.');
    for (let i=0; i<fields.length; i++) {
        let f = fields[i];
        if (f.indexOf("[]") > -1) {
            let arrayfield = f.replace('[]', '');
            f = fields[++i];
            object[arrayfield].forEach((el, idx) => {
                if (isEmpty(el[f])) {
                    el[f]= {};
                }
                if (i === fields.length - 1) {
                    el[f] = value;
                }
            });
            object = object[arrayfield];
        }
        else {
            if (isEmpty(object[f])) {
                object[f] = {};
            }
            if (i === fields.length - 1) {
                object[f] = value;
            }
            object = object[f];
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to walk through branches as you find these, so that each branch entry becomes a new `deepSet`.

**Example**

```
const deepSet = (obj, path, value) => {
  const re = /(\.|\[\]\.)/g;
  let i = 0, match = null;
  while (match = re.exec(path)) {
    const sep = match[0];
    const {length} = sep;
    const {index} = match;
    obj = obj[path.slice(i, index)];
    i = index + length;
    if (1 < length) {
      path = path.slice(i);
      obj.forEach(obj => {
        deepSet(obj, path, value);
      });
      return;
    }
  }
  obj[path.slice(i)] = value;
};

var obj = { one: { two: [{three: [{four:'a'}, {four:'b'}]}, {three: [{four:'a'}, {four:'b'}]}]}};
deepSet(obj, 'one.two[].three[].four', 'yay');
```

This will produce the expected result:

```
{
  "one": {
    "two": [
      {
        "three": [
          {
            "four": "yay"
          },
          {
            "four": "yay"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "three": [
          {
            "four": "yay"
          },
          {
            "four": "yay"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Hope it helps or, at least, it gave you a hint

Answer (score 0):

You could take a recursive approach

```js
const
    deepSet = (object, path, value) => {
        let [key, ...keys] = path.split('.');

        if (key.endsWith('[]')) {
            object = object[key.slice(0, -2)];
            Object.keys(object).forEach(k => {
                if (keys.length) deepSet(object[k], keys.join('.'), value);
                else object[k] = value;
            });
        } else {
            if (keys.length) deepSet(object[key], keys.join('.'), value);
            else object[key] = value;
        }
    },
    object = { one: { two: [{ three: [{ four: 'a' }, { four: 'b' }] }, { three: [{ four: 'a' }, { four: 'b' }] }] } };


deepSet(object, 'one.two[].three[].four', 'yay');

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```